# Why does a file move/copy function only move one file at a time when using the “*” wildcard?

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, wildcards, function

```
function mv1 { mv -n "$1" "targetdir" -v |wc -l ;}
mv1 *.png
```

It does only move the first `.png` file it finds, not all of them.

How can I make the command apply to all files that match the wildcards?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`mv1 *.png` first expands the wildcard pattern `*.png` into the list of matching file names, then passes that list of file names to the function.

Then, inside the function `$1` means: take the first argument to the function, split it where it contains whitespace, and replace any of the whitespace-separated parts that contain wildcard characters and match at least one file name by the list of matching file names. Sounds complicated? It is, and this behavior is only occasionally useful and is often problematic. This splitting and matching behavior only occurs if `$1` occurs outside of double quotes, so the fix is easy: use double quotes. **[Always put double quotes around variable substitutions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters)** unless you have a good reason not to.

For example, if the current directory contains the two files `A* algorithm.png` and `graph1.png`, then `mv1 *.png` passes `A* algorithm.png` as the first argument to the function and `graph1.png` as the second argument. Then `$1` is split into `A*` and `algorithm.png`. The pattern `A*` matches `A* algorithm.png`, and `algorithm.png` doesn't contain wildcard characters. So the function ends up running `mv` with the arguments `-n`, `A* algorithm.png`, `algorithm.png`, `targetdir` and `-v`. If you correct the function to

```
function mv1 { mv -n "$1" "targetdir" -v |wc -l ;}
```

then it will correctly move the first file.

To process *all* the arguments, tell the shell to process all arguments and not just the first. You can use `"$@"` to mean the full list of arguments passed to the function.

```
function mv1 { mv -n "$@" "targetdir" -v |wc -l ;}
```

This is almost correct, but it still fails if a file name happens to begin with the character `-`, because `mv` will treat that argument as an option. Pass `--` to `mv` to tell it “no more options after this point”. This is a very common convention that most commands support.

```
function mv1 { mv -n -v -- "$@" "targetdir" |wc -l ;}
```

A remaining problem is that if `mv` fails, this function returns a success status, because the exit status of commands on the left-hand side of a pipe is ignored. In bash (or ksh), you can use `set -o pipefail` to make the pipeline fail. Note that setting this option may cause other code running in the same shell to fail, so you should set it locally in the function, which is possible since bash 4.4.

```
function mv1 {
  local -
  set -o pipefail
  mv -n -v -- "$@" "targetdir" | wc -l
}
```

In earlier versions, setting `pipefail` would be fragile, so it would be better to check `PIPESTATUS` explicitly instead.

```
function mv1 {
  mv -n -v -- "$@" "targetdir" | wc -l
  ((!${PIPESTATUS[0] && !${PIPESTATUS[1]}}))
}
```

Comment: I already made that first correction before I posted the question, but I forgot to correct it in the question as well.

Comment: “Pass -- to mv to tell it “no more options after this point”.” – Thanks alot. Didn't knew that until now.

Comment: cite for "$1" splitting at whitespace

Comment: You could also use `return "${PIPESTATUS[0]}"` (immediately after the `mv | wc` pipeline) instead of messing with `pipefail`.

Comment: @Jasen It doesn't. Where did you read that? `$1`, without quotes, splits at whitespace.

Comment: A much better idea than the unreliable `set -o; ...; set +o` is to make all `set -o` options (dynamically) local to the function with `mv1(){ local -; set -o pipefail; ...; }`.

Answer (score 3):

`$1` is the first argument to the function, here the first file that matches `*.png`. I guess that `"$@"` is what you want to use instead of `$1`.

Comment: `$@` or `$*` is very rarely useful. To take all the arguments, use `"$@"`. [The double quotes are very important](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters).

Comment: Thanks alot for showing me `$@`! Very useful!

Answer (score -2):

#### You would have to use `mv1 \*.png`.

When interacting with functions, the Linux Terminal does not pass the asterisk directly to the command, but selects the first matching parameter and passes that one to the command.

To allow the asterisk to pass through directly, one needs to escape the asterisk using a backslash.

Comment: You understood part of the problem right, but your solution is not good. In particular, it doesn't work with file names containing whitespace. See my answer for a correct solution and explanations.

Comment: @Gilles Thank you for the answer.

Comment: @Gilles …but does that really justify the downvote that was hammered onto my answer?

Comment: This answer doesn't answer this part of the question: *How can I make the command apply to all files that match the wildcards?* I can't see an easy way to expand this answer, because Bash doesn't have a safe way to apply globbing only to the value of a veriable (e.g. if `$1` is `*.png`).